# Sort ListViewGroups of a ListView alphabetically

Tags: .net, winforms, listview, sorting, alphabetical

Is it possible to sort all ListViewGroups of a Windows Forms ListView alphabetically at runtime?

Or do I have to manually implement sorting when I'm adding a group (using the "Insert" method of the ListViewGroupCollection)? If this is the case, can someone give me an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WinForms ListView, you have to do the sorting manually:

```
ListViewGroup[] groups = new ListViewGroup[this.listView1.Groups.Count];

this.listView1.Groups.CopyTo(groups, 0);

Array.Sort(groups, new GroupComparer());

this.listView1.BeginUpdate();
this.listView1.Groups.Clear();
this.listView1.Groups.AddRange(groups);
this.listView1.EndUpdate();

...

class GroupComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object objA, object objB)
    {
        return ((ListViewGroup)objA).Header.CompareTo(((ListViewGroup)objB).Header);
    }
}
```

Groups in .NET ListView are quite nasty - they look and behave like a mix between old Win32 ListView and Windows Explorer...

So I would recommend you [Better ListView component](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview) which supports sorting groups out of the box:

```
this.betterListView1.Groups.Sort(new GroupComparer());

...

class GroupComparer : IComparer<BetterListViewGroup>
{
    public int Compare(BetterListViewGroup groupA, BetterListViewGroup groupB)
    {
        return groupA.Header.CompareTo(groupB.Header);
    }
}
```

Furthermore, the groups look and behave just like in Windows Explorer, are collapsible and no flickering happens even when you sort them.

Comment: Thanks! Group sorting was just missing from my ListView component, I already implemented collapsible groups and double buffering / uxstyles.