# Listview sort groups (C#, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, grouping

I have a list which get dynamically filled. Within the lists the items are grouped. I am trying to sort the groups (not the items within the group) because somehow there are completely mixed up.

I was able to sort the items within the group but didn't find a way to programming sort the groups. Does anyone can give me a hint how to do it or why they are unsorted in the first place?

Init Code:

```
_lvUsers.ItemsSource = _config.listTestBenches;
CollectionView view = CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_lvUsers.ItemsSource);
PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("type");
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
```

Update GUI:

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_config.listTestBenches);
view.Refresh();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546968/sort-listviewgroups-of-a-listview-alphabetically . Looks like you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Just att a `SortDescription` to the same `CollectionView`:

```
_lvUsers.ItemsSource = _config.listTestBenches;
CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_lvUsers.ItemsSource);
PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("type");
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("type", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

Comment: @user3077796: Did you try this?

Answer (score -1):

This should help:

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding list}" x:Key="cvs">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <!--This will sort groups-->
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="type" />
        <!--This will sort items-->
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="sortItemName"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <dat:PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="type" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```